# Jabberwocky Question

Tags: knowledge, no-computers

What's a good word to describe 'Jabberwocky,' by Lewis Carroll?

As a reminder, here's the first stanza:

> 'Twass brillig, and the sluithy toves
>   Did gyrre and gimble in the wabe;
>   All mimsy werre the boerogoves,
>   And the moame raths loutgrabe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turns out:

> The first stanza is misquoted; there are some errors. Namely, some letters are added as follows:
>
>  'Twas**s** brillig, and the sl**u**ithy toves
>  Did gy**r**re and gimble in the wabe;
>  All mimsy we**r**re the bo**e**rogoves,
>  And the mo**a**me raths **l**outgrabe.

Therefore, the answer is

> these added letters: **SURREAL**.